# Is it possible to filter the Recently Viewed object list view by record type so it can be inline edited

Tags: record-type, list-view, recentlyviewed

It is my understanding that other than customizing the fields that can be displayed in the Recently Viewed list views, we cannot add a record type filter so that we can inline edit from that list view (when a record type exists on the object).

However, on the Salesforce help documentation, it specifies that we can predefine a list view with a record type, "You can inline edit in Recently Viewed or Team list views that are predefined to contain only one record type."

If this is true, how do we do predefine a record type for the Recently Viewed list view?

The link to article:  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customviews_edit_inline_listview_lex_considerations.htm&type=5